# Implement mobile push notification server

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement a push notification server which should send push notifications via apn (apple), gcm (Google) and wns (windows). I already checked push platforms like the one from Amazon, but none of these do met the requirement that I maybe later want to implement an additional service provider (e.g. for location based push). In addition two that nearly no provider offers an api so that various systems can connect to it.

Want kind of libraries or frameworks do you know to send push notifications in an easy way?

I have already seen https://github.com/rs/pushd but I am searching for an java / Javascript based solution. Some others doesn't provide solutions for Windows.

Does anybody has any tips?

Thanks, 
Fahim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are working well for me.

Apple:
https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns

Google:
https://github.com/google/gcm

Windows:
https://github.com/fernandospr/java-wns